# Find a word in a string and wrap it not working - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to wrap words found in `product-single__description` in `<b>` tags but so far nothing is being highlighted.

These are the tags

```
<ul class="product-tags">
<li><a>one</a></li>
<li><a>two</a></li>
<li><a>three</a></li>
<li><a>four</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to highlight any tags found in the `p` element below in `b`

```
<div class="product-single__description">
<p>Sentence number one</p>
<p>Sentence number two</p>
<p>Sentence number three</p>
<p>Sentence number four</p>
</div>
```

It should look like this after the javascript runs

```
<div class="product-single__description">
<p>Sentence number <b>one</b></p>
<p>Sentence number <b>two</b></p>
<p>Sentence number <b>three</b></p>
<p>Sentence number <b>four</b></p>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery.

```
$("ul.product-tags li").each(function() {
     var tag = $(this).children("a").text();


   $('.product-single__description').children("p").each(function() {
     var str = $(this).text();
     var reg = new RegExp(tag, 'gi');
     var txt = textDiv.replace(reg, function(str) {
       return "<b>" + str + "</b>"
     });
    $(this).text(txt);

   });
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L4hnenss/2/  I still can't get it working. How do i solve?

Comment: uhm. what's `textDiv`? did you mean `str`? also, `.text()` would just result in html being placed in the paragraph in text form, so you'd see `<b>` on teh page.

Comment: thanks, i get <b> tags wrapped around but not in html format?

Comment: Right, so use the html inserting method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couple of issues... You are using the text function to assign html in jquery.  Additionally, you are using a variable called textDiv that doesn't seem to be defined, so I changed that to txt.

Here's a functional version of the code given:

```
$("ul.product-tags li").each(function() {
     var tag = $(this).children("a").html();


   $('.product-single__description').children("p").each(function() {
     var str = $(this).html();
     var reg = new RegExp(tag, 'gi');
     var txt = str.replace(reg, function(str) {
       return "<b>" + str + "</b>"
     });
    $(this).html(txt);

   });
});
```